# socket.io&node.js) How to disconnect mobile browser long polling

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm using socket.io and node.js.

For the browsers that support websocket have no problem.

For the pc browsers that are connected with long-polling, I can use onbeforeunload and force to close the connection.

What about mobile browsers that are using long-polling for connection? It seems like onbeforeunload doesn't work on mobile browsers.

Do I need to wait until the long-polling connection closed by itself?

Thanks for your help!